# Uncaught ReferenceError: variable is not defined? (no jQuery involved)

Tags: javascript, console.log, referenceerror

this is my first question on stackoverflow.

I am learning about javascript and decided to start a project.
I'm making a scoreboard to keep track of the score during table tennis. I managed to make this work and decided to add some features like a match history and show which player has to serve.
However, I'm stuck with the ReferenceError. In most other questions about this, people just forgot to add the variable or it had something to do with jquery. I don't think that's my problem.

In table tennis the player with serve changes every 2 points. I decided to add scorePlayer1 and scorePlayer2 to make a totalScore. When this is divided by 2, I can check if this is an integer, and if it is, the player with serve changes. However, whatever I try, the variable totalScore is not defined.

I learned HTML/CSS first at w3schools.com and later used it to learn javascript.
I have pasted the code into multiple syntax checkers, but got no errors.

The button is there to pick the serve player. Then, I want to swith the right to serve to the opposite player after 2 points are scored. I tried this with function changeServePlayer. However, when I try this in Chrome and type in the console: totalScore, it returns the Uncaught ReferenceError. Why does this happen or is there a better way to achieve the goal?

Here's code I used:

```js
var currentScorePlayerOne = 0;
var currentScorePlayerTwo = 0;
var currentServePlayer;
var totalScore;

window.addEventListener("keyup", checkKeyPress);

function checkKeyPress(key) {
  if (key.keyCode == "90" && currentScorePlayerOne != 0) { //Z
    document.getElementById('scorePlayerOne').innerHTML = --currentScorePlayerOne;
    changeServePlayer();
    changeServeIcon();
  }
  if (key.keyCode == "88") { //X
    document.getElementById('scorePlayerOne').innerHTML = ++currentScorePlayerOne;
    changeServePlayer();
    changeServeIcon();
  }
  if (key.keyCode == "78" && currentScorePlayerTwo != 0) { //N
    document.getElementById('scorePlayerTwo').innerHTML = --currentScorePlayerTwo;
    changeServePlayer();
    changeServeIcon();
  }
  if (key.keyCode == "77") { //M
    document.getElementById('scorePlayerTwo').innerHTML = ++currentScorePlayerTwo;
    changeServePlayer();
    changeServeIcon();
  }
  updateSet();
}

function updateSet() {
  if (currentScorePlayerOne > 10 && currentScorePlayerOne > currentScorePlayerTwo + 1) {
    resetScores();
  }
  if (currentScorePlayerTwo > 10 && currentScorePlayerTwo > currentScorePlayerOne + 1) {
    resetScores();
  }
}


function resetScores() {
  currentScorePlayerOne = 0;
  currentScorePlayerTwo = 0;
  document.getElementById('scorePlayerOne').innerHTML = currentScorePlayerOne;
  document.getElementById('scorePlayerTwo').innerHTML = currentScorePlayerTwo;
}

function changeServePlayer() {
  totalScore = currentScorePlayerOne + currentScorePlayerTwo;
  Number.isInteger(totalScore / 2);
  if (Number.isInteger == true && totalScore != 0 && currentServePlayer == 1) {
    currentServePlayer = 2;
  }
  if (Number.isInteger == true && totalScore != 0 && currentServePlayer == 2) {
    currentServePlayer = 1;
  }
}

function changeServeIcon() {
  if (currentServePlayer == 1) {
    document.getElementById('serveP1').style.opacity = "1";
    document.getElementById('serveP2').style.opacity = "0.2";
  } else {
    document.getElementById('serveP2').style.opacity = "1";
    document.getElementById('serveP1').style.opacity = "0.2";
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="Scoreboard1javascript.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <button type="button" onclick="chooseServingPlayer()">
   Serve
  </button>

  <script>
    var randomServeNumber;

    function chooseServingPlayer() {
      if (currentScorePlayerOne == 0 && currentScorePlayerTwo == 0) {
        document.getElementById('serveP1').style.opacity = "0.2";
        document.getElementById('serveP2').style.opacity = "0.2";
        randomServeNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
        if (randomServeNumber > 5) {
          currentServePlayer = 1;
          changeServeIcon();
        } else {
          currentServePlayer = 2;
          changeServeIcon();
        }
      }
    }

    function changeServeIcon() {
      if (currentServePlayer == 1) {
        document.getElementById('serveP1').style.opacity = "1";
        document.getElementById('serveP2').style.opacity = "0.2";
      } else {
        document.getElementById('serveP2').style.opacity = "1";
        document.getElementById('serveP1').style.opacity = "0.2";
      }
    }
  </script>

  <nav>
    <img src="tafeltennisbat.png" alt="serve" style="width: 50px; height: 50px; opacity: 0.2" id="serveP1"> Score P1
  </nav>
  <nav>
    Score P2
    <img src="tafeltennisbat.png" alt="serve" style="width: 50px; height: 50px; opacity: 0.2" id="serveP2">
  </nav>
  <nav id="scorePlayerOne" style="font-size: 50px">
    0
  </nav>
  <nav id="scorePlayerTwo" style="font-size: 50px">
    0
  </nav>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: open `{` are not closed in `if`

Comment: The code lacks `checkKeyPress` function, you should wrap the code between the line you set the keyup listener and the line declaring `changeServePlayer`, within the function declaring `checkKeyPress`. If there haven't been any errors in "_multiple syntax checkers_", I assume the lacking closing curly braces are typos in the post only?

Comment: This is an error caused by a typo, and as such, should be closed.

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry. The if statement not closed was just a copy paste mistake.

Comment: Since you’ve looked at other questions and been able to see that they forgot to define their variables, check your code again and ask yourself this question: "Where have I defined `key`?"

Comment: @Lennholm oh, sorry. I forgot to add that line in this post too. The checkKeyPress function works just fine. When the key is pressed, 1 gets added onto the currentScorePlayer variable. The problem is the totalScore variable.

Comment: The only problem with that code, as far as I can tell, is the previously mentioned typo. You need to provide a *tested* [mcve] (ideally using the live demo feature of the question editor)

Comment: `Number.isInteger == true ` <-- wrong

Comment: You should learn about the [modulus operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder)

Comment: @Quentin should I remove the current code and replace it with a demo, or keep this part and add the demo part.

Comment: @epascarello do you think that would solve the error, or is that a seperate problem?

Comment: I honestly have no clue how you get an error. Also does not help that the code is not complete. The error I pointed out is an issue. Not sure what you expect it to do.

Comment: Re edit: I can't work out how to trigger the error.

Comment: @Quentin I explained it in an edit in the question itself. The error only occurs when the variable is typed in the console.

Comment: @Drumstick — https://i.imgur.com/E1QcHS1.jpg — I still can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Quentin I see. Here's a screenshot of the error: https://imgur.com/a/UAGch5a  -  Thank you for your help so far!

Comment: @Drumstick — You reproducing the error doesn't really help. The code you've provided works when I test it.

Comment: @Quentin oh wow the variable totalScore finally works! I will point down where it goes wrong in my own code. Can you see why the player with serve doesn't change after 2 points though?

Comment: @Quentin I just figured it out... after three days. In the html file I was referencing an old javascript. Every change I made did absolutely nothing. Well... Thanks for taking your time to help me !

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to check which file I was referencing in my html script. I was referencing an old version of the javascript, which made every change I made in javascript useless.

It can be really that stupid sometimes...